# First and last element in numpy array comes as NaN while reading with genfromtxt

Tags: python, numpy

My csv file looks like this https://extendsclass.com/csv-editor.html#ef4a190

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('2857_54065_N.csv', encoding=None, delimiter=',')
my_data
```

Which gives result like this.

array([ nan, 636., 654., ..., 572., 547.,  nan])

Why first andlast element comes as `nan` ?

Comment: I'd suggest using Pandas.  That method is for files containing nothing but numbers, while that file also contains column names

Answer (score 0):

Just open the csv-file in a text editor and remove the quotation marks at the beginning and end of the file. The table at the given URL contains only one column and one row, thus returning a single entry with a list of numbers (in quotation marks), .

Hence, the first and last entry include a `"`-character which cannot be interpreted as number and thus renders `nan`.

Comment: @lecraminors: if you check the csv link I added, there is no `"` in beginning and end

Comment: true, yet the file that you download contains them, since you put everything in just one cell instead using the table as such... 

See an updated version of your list here and observe the difference:
https://extendsclass.com/csv-editor.html#6d1dd6d